# is this true ? what about Expected SARSA and double Q-Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, sarsa, temporal-difference

I‘m studying `Reinforcement Learning` and I’m facing a problem understanding the difference between SARSA, Q-Learning, expected SARSA, Double Q Learning and temporal difference. Can you please explain the difference and tell me when to use each? And what is the effect on e-greedy and greedy move?

SARSA :

I’m in state `St`, an action is chosen with the help of the policy so it moves me to another state `St+1` Depending on the Policy in state `St+1` an action is made so my `Reward` in `St` is gonna be updated due to  the expected `Reward` in the look ahead state `St+1`.

```
Q(S, A) ← Q(S, A) + α[ R + γQ(S , A ) − Q(S, A)]
```

Q-Learning:

I’m in state `St`, an action was chosen with the help of the policy so it moves me to state `St+1`, this time it’s not gonna depend on the  policy instead it’s gonna observe the maximum of the expected `Reward` (greedy `Reward`) in state `St+1` and through it the reward of state `St` is going to be updated.

```
Q(S, A) ← Q(S, A) + α [R + γ max Q(S , a) − Q(S, A)]
```

Expected SARSA:

it’s gonna be same as Q-learning instead of updating my `Reward` with the help of the greedy move in `St+1` I take the expected reward of all actions :

```
Q(St , At) ← Q(St , At) + α[Rt+1 + γE[Q(St+1, At+1)|St+1] − Q(St , At)]
```

Temporal difference :

The current `Reward` is gonna be updated using the observed reward `Rt+1` and the estimate value `V(St+1)` At `timepoint t + 1`:

```
V (St) ← V (St) + α[Rt+1 + γV (St+1) − V (St)]
```

is it true what I got or am I missing something? And What about Double Q Learning?

With 0.5 probabilility:

```
Q1(S, A) ← Q1(S, A) + α R + γQ2 S , argmaxa Q1(S , a)  − Q1(S, A)
```

else:

```
Q2(S, A) ← Q2(S, A) + α R + γQ1 S , argmaxa Q2(S , a)  − Q2(S, A)
```

Can someone explain it please!!